# How to inject a custom message in joomla update without touching the core code

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

I created my own component in joomla and I want to show a custom warning when my users want to auto update the component. When they try to update it joomla could not find the zip file and return a warning in this file:
`administrator\components\com_installer\models\update.php line:434`

```
if (!$p_file)
{
    JError::raiseWarning('', JText::sprintf('COM_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED', $url));

    return false;
}
```

How I can inject a custom message in joomla update without touching the core code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<jdoc:include type="modules" />` to your index.php template file -  this will show error messages -  and override the core file you want.

Example: If you want to override a view of certain component, you can copy the view and paste it into `templates/your-template/code/component-name/views/` (you have to create folder and subfolders). Joomla will look in the folder you created for overrided files.

More information https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Tell me if it solves your problem.

Comment: I can not force my users to install any plugins to override administrator\components\com_installer\models\update.php , Am I right about it or it does not need to install override plugin?

Comment: No, you don't need it. You can override the files directly in your template by copying the file `update.php` located in `administrator\components\com_installer\models` and paste it into a folder you will create. The path should be as following: 
 `templates/your-template/code/component-name/models/`. You can edit the file without having to modify the core file. Joomla will look for that folder you created and will use this overrided file.

Comment: I tested it and it is not working. Also it does not make any sense that joomla search in template/your-template/code folder, there is no reason that joomla do it, can you give me some links?

Comment: In that link you attached to your answer writes: 
This method only works if you install and enable the 3rd party MVC plugin joomla-override found on github - or provide your own equivalent plugin. It is fine for advanced developers - just be aware that this is not part of Joomla! Core code

Comment: Oh thak you for your clarifications. In the documentation it said that there are two methods, plugin and overrides...it was supposed to work. But I know that template overrides work without plugins. If you need to override any template file just copy this file to `your-template\html\module-name\view-name`

Comment: Ummm, I think one of us has the wrong end of the stick. I read the original question as he was not the site owner, he was a component developer and wanted to get a message to the site owners that were using his component. So he would have no legitimate access to the template being used.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can. The update process isn't supposed to involve the component being updated until after the download succeeds; everything before that point is rightly the domain of the system, not the component. (After all, if the download fails, there's nothing for the system to read a message from, and the component being updated isn't invoked at all during the process, in no small part because PHP really doesn't like updates being made to code that's already been loaded.)

There is a long shot attempt at a solution for future customers: Maybe package your component with a plugin that runs when onInstallerAfterInstaller fires, where you can look for the the package being installed and the reason it failed. It might work, but that wouldn't help current customers and is way too complex for me to be happy with. (I like simpler approaches, I just don't see how this gets simple. If you do, have at it with my blessing.)

Answer (score 0):

onExtensionAfterUpdate is the plugin method you're looking for. You can add this method to your existing plugin. If I understand your issue correctly, `raiseWarning` has already been called, so you could just simply unset it, and set your own error text.